# Django REST Framework - Can not update fields of model by serializer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want update model's fields with save to DB. I wrote this code. But I can not update model. `serializer.is_valid()` return value is True. Why I can not?

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
serializer = PostSerializer(post, data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

Comment: Is it possible to see more of the view code? Could you also post the code for the `PostSerializer` and `Post` model?

Comment: Is your `PostSerializer` a `ModelSerializer`?

Comment: sorry, it was a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a misunderstanding.

Comment: I think you had better delete this question yourself

Comment: can not delete :/